# Why is XML good for data files? 

Tags: xml

Recently the research group I have been working in have been working on some simulation codes.

For the codes we have the main C++ files containing the code, 
a text file containing input parameters for the simulation. The data of the simulation at every time step is spitted out in the form of columnar data where each column representing some physical quantity position, pressure, etc.  and each row represents a grid point.

My boss has now asked me to switch the data format of the input-parameter-file and output data files to the XML format from its present key-value , key-value nature.  He seems to be
very poor at his explanations since his English pretty much sucks. Its been two times now that he ranted about the superiority about XML without me understanding a word.

Now, Let me say I am just your average C / C++ / Python programmer interested in scientific computing, and I have no back-ground in Computer Engineering subjects like databases or web development that XML seems to be used most in.

Can anyone give me a short explanation of this or else point me to some resources which 
offer a gentle explanation of the concepts with simple yet non-trivial examples without all the yoga, chanting, incense burning , and ugly technical vocabulary (which keep requiring me to do endless googling) that all the XML tutorials seem to be filled with.

If someone can give some  explicit real-life  examples of where and how the XML data format is used in some
**applied mathematics** codes that will really be helpful.

Comment: The problem is that your program is the only program that can process your input files and produce your output files. XML is more readable than CSV (especially if you don't output the column names as the first row in your CSV). You might spend hours on this program so you remember the columns off by heart, whereas your boss probably has to multitask and time-division multiplex his a55 off to keep the project (and you) economically viable to his boss. Learn to be a good follower because there are very few jobs for people who want to be the leader (from personal experience).

Comment: What if you add XML as an alternative format for input and output? It may be politically advantageous to conceal the continued existence of the CSV format, but it seems rash to rip it all out and switch over. and that way you use XML for what it's good at, data interchange.

Answer (score 6):

Briefly, XML offer the ability to be interoperable with a wide variety of software, since XML data can be exchanged  by using the XML language.

For example, the same data can be included in an HTML page for display, or can be read "as is" by other application aware of the data schema (XML schema), or can be transformed in any text format by using XSLT. (i.e. XML to CSV).

In conclusion, XML can be ported more easily than any other data format.

Of course this is not the only benefit of using XML for data: XML can validate a document against its schema (for correctness), the data can be queried with a declaration language (XPath).

A disadvatage of XML, for application that requires/produce lots of data is that XML is verbose (w.r.t. any binary data format): think how to save an image, for instance, in XML... That would be cumbersome... Of course you can include binary data in the XML document (by using base64 encoding), but in this cases (where most of the data is stored in base64) it make no sense to use XML.

Answer (score 4):

Also, XML is a very flexible format. It's easy to store data, the structure of which varies, while maintaining a clear, formal definition thanks to DTD, XSD or RelaxNG.

For example, compared to a table, it allows you to eliminate possible empty cells, which (for large enough data sets) can even compensate for its verbosity.

Tabular data:

```
 ID  | attribute1 | attribute2 | attribute3 | attribute4 | attribute5 | etc.
 1   |     1      |     3      |      8     |    null    |    7       |  ...
 2   |     4      |    null    |     null   |    null    |    13      |  ...
 3   |     4      |    null    |      1     |     12     |   null     |  ...
```

XML:

```
<rows>
  <row id="1">
    <attribute1>1</attribute1>
    <attribute2>3</attribute2>
    <attribute3>8</attribute3>
    <attribute5>7</attribute5>
  </row>
  <row id="2">
    <attribute1>4</attribute1>
    <attribute5>13</attribute5>
  </row>
  <row id="3">
    <attribute1>4</attribute1>
    <attribute3>1</attribute3>
    <attribute4>12</attribute4>
  </row>
</rows>
```

Not to mention the fact that each row could have a complex, individual structure.
You could describe a very long polynomial expression or literally any other function this way.

I'm sure many applications implementing advanced mathematics use XML. I know Mathematica allows XML export. So do Matlab and R.

Another advantage of using XML is that it's both easy to parse by machines and pretty readable by humans. You don't need to decode it (like binary) and you can clearly see the structure of data (unlike csv or many other formats).

Its popularity and abundance of tools are not to be ignored either.

Answer (score 2):

Using XML maximizes the long-term value of your data, because it is represented in a form that is independent of how you intend to use it and indepedent of any particular software environment. That's basically it. As often, when you treat software and data as a long-term asset then you may have to do a bit of "over-engineering" in terms of meeting the immediate short-term goals, but you (or your boss) is taking a calculated gamble that the investment will pay off in the long term.

Answer (score 1):

Think about a world where any software or hardware uses its own format. Microsoft Word '.doc' files have a certain structure (to define fonts, dimensions, alignments, ecc) different from, let's say, a'.pdf'.

I could go on infinitely, telling you about some formats being different from others, but in their results (a text file, a video, an image) being like all the other. The internet is pretty much overloaded with people asking for "how can I open that file in that OS?" or "how can I open that file in that application", ecc.

**Software companies has never really wanted to adapt their softwares to the existing standards, rather they leave this pain-in-the-a** to you by creating new standards (often not compatible with others).** There's one exception: HTML.

Any browser developer had to made an application which must be the better, the lighter, the cooler as possible to do what? Just read and render an existing format: HTML pages.

Told that, you may guess why XML is a good format to use ;)
Ideally, everything should be in .txt only format. Now tell me, could you write an XML file without an XML editor (just by using the notepad)? Can you do the same with a pdf? Or with a doc?

As far as I know there are no "explicit real-life examples of where and how the XML data format is used in some applied mathematics codes" but, unfortunately, computer science is not only about "applied mathematics" but also about some minor crap we have to care about, like formats.

Answer (score 0):

XML is *not* appropriate for data structures or key-value pairs. Use JSON or YAML for those. On the other hand, XML is appropriate for document markup.