# What exactly is an XML file?

Tags: xml

I've been working on various projects and have been seeing XML files pop up everywhere.

I understand that XML stands for *Extensible Markup Language* and don't necessarily do anything themselves (other than describe data), but I'm curious why these files are so common among many different project types and what makes them so effective.

Comment: If you only think that HTML is a form of XML, you might understand why XML is a very important language

Comment: [XML for configuration files, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791761/xml-for-configuration-files-why)

Comment: [Why use XML as a storage format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285802/why-use-xml-as-a-storage-format)

Comment: [When is it OK to use an XML file to save information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106210/when-is-it-ok-to-use-an-xml-file-to-save-information)

Comment: [Why is XML used for the creation of UI layouts in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5645468/why-is-xml-used-for-the-creation-of-ui-layouts-in-android)

Comment: [Why is XML good for data files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777148/why-is-xml-good-for-data-files)

Answer (score 1):

[**XML**](https://www.w3.org/XML/) is a [**W3C standard format**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/) for marking-up text data with metadata.

It's most useful for documents, although it's also been applied to structured data such as configuration files.

Its power derives from its

- widespread acceptance: *XML is all about agreement*
- extensibility (via schema definition languages such as DTD, XSD, RelaxNG, and Schematron)
- ease of selection and transformation (via XPath and XSLT)
- common tools and libraries (such as parsers) in nearly all programming languages.

Comment: XML is a subset of SGML originally intended to replace HTML on the Web (as XHTML). However, only SVG and MathML actually became broadly used on the Web.

Comment: @imhotap: Perhaps your comment was intended for another answer.  I chose not to elaborate XML's origin and relationship to HTML for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I think XML's origin - as a simplified SGML subset - and original purpose - to replace HTML - are very important facts when talking about XML in general. Also, that XML was developed as part of a SGML revision effort by W3C/ERB. They're stated almost in the first sentence of the XML specs. But feel free to ignore or remove my comment.

Answer (score 1):

1. a text file
2. a well structured text file that use XML Language (inspired by SGML)
3. a file that is often used to save technical data

XML becomes popular because it was one of the first formats that are well defined over different separated IT worlds and there is an eco-system with additional tools

Comment: XML isn't just inspired by SGML, but a proper subset of SGML as of ISO/IEC 8879 Annex K.

Answer (score 1):

Storing data in XML files is much easier with the predefined tags that are available and can be easily shared across different platforms for example communicating between JAVA & PHP using XML webservices.